# Username bug in flair

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair

The flair for my network profile has a badly HTML-entitied apostrophe in my name:

[image]

It's only the network flair, though. Site-specific flairs are OK:

[image]

Could someone fix it?

Comment: Be proud of it.

Comment: It's about time MSO had a tag for your username ;)

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if you added the apostrophe to your name just to reveal obscure bugs.

Comment: The global flair [doesn't like us that much](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126828/172936) :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed now, though it might take up to 24 more hours to completely fall out of cache.

Network flair data comes from the [Stack Exchange API v2](https://api.stackexchange.com/), and we were mistakenly using a "[safe filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters)" in our [query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=3479&filter=-pez6l2a7Mgp&site=english).

Answer (score 2):

Which is strange, because the flair is PNG, not HTML.. {/Checks code} Oh, I see.. The code consists of a [server kitty](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Server-kitty.jpg) taking pictures of badly rendered HTML.

Seriously though, I would say that it's the result of stackexchange.com/stackauth.com escaping your username when passing it to the flair script, while *.SE.com doesn't do that.. Which makes sense, since the code behind stackexchange.com and *.SE is different. But we need an SE member to be sure.

Till the SE team feeds that server kitty, I suggest you check out the links at the bottom of this [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/).