# Combined Stack Exchange flair makes me look creepy

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, combined-flair

There seems to be an issue with my combined Stack Exchange flair.

All of the individual (site specific) flairs appear to be working (and displaying) correctly -

[image: Flair]

Only the combined flair has the problem :

[image]

Makes me look like this  :
[image]

This makes it look like I'm [Mr.Trollololo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Z4m4lnjxkY) and **extremely** interested in my rep count.  While this is true the main problem is that it looks like I have 6K on SO (**Don't jump the gun! - I'll get there soon enough!**).  Also it does not show my other accounts.

The example is taken from MSO - but the same problem appears on all the other SE sites I've looked at.

Is this an issue with Gravatar? I *believe* **not** - That specific image is not from Gravatar rather taken from my `****book` account.

I have cleared cache and tested this on

- Chrome 17.0.963.83 (Ubuntu 10.04 + WinXP + Win7)
- Firefox 11.0 (Ubuntu 10.04)

Please don't make me look more creepy (than I actually am) in my flair! :)

---

Seems to me that the issue is simply a larger picture being used.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/504135887/picture?type=large  
                      instead of  
http://graph.facebook.com/504135887/picture?type=small
```

Or that the resizing is being skipped.

---

Direct URLS for your convenience

- Combined flair - https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/268952.png
- Regular MSO Flair - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/172936.png

---

I really hope this is not contagious...

[image]
[image]

Comment: If this is **not** a bug - I promise to work very hard to get to 6K on [SO] so that my flair won't be misleading. ^_^

Comment: Oh hey! I just noticed for the first time what you did there with your gravatar on Meta—decolorizing and reversing your picture. I see your posts a lot on Meta, but never on SO since I avoid anything with "facebook" tags like the plague.

Comment: @cod - Understandable!  And yes - decolorizing to keep in touch with the color scheme here :)

Comment: [Maybe I shouldn't use my `****book` photo...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122810/system-message-about-db-maintenance-on-facebook-stackoverflow-com#comment326758_122810)

Comment: How did you get it to use your "****book" account picture in the first place?

Comment: Hahaha, the greyscale image is a cool idea!

Comment: @min - I'd tell you how - but I fear that some users will plan a lynch against me :P

Comment: @Pekka, Lix: ChrisF's [SO gravatar is grayscaled](http://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) and his [MSO gravatar is colorized](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) :)

Comment: @Bolt - Ah yes - but no horizontal flip :P  If you start something you got to finish it.  No offence to ChrisF of course :P

Comment: That's a fantastic glitch.

Comment: My gravatar is already grayscaled, maybe I should colour it for main :)

Comment: (@minitechη, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127271/i-created-an-account-using-google-openid-on-stack-overflow-and-the-profile-pict/127286#127286).)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is fixed now, though it might take up to 24 hours for the creepy version to fall out of your browser's cache.

[image]

As you noted, your profile image comes from Facebook, not Gravatar, and the abnormal (non-50x50) size wasn't being properly handled by the flair-generation code.

Comment: Thanks so much! Clearing cache indeed un-creepyfied my flair. :)