# Why has my voting limit been changing frequently?

Tags: support, vote-count, voting-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits)

I don't know why my voting limit has been changing frequently.  Earlier, I was having 40 votes per day, but now the limit has dropped to 32 or 33. Today I voted only 33 times. Why is it so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a base level of 30 votes which can be used on questions or answers.

In addition you have **up to** 10 extra votes which can only be cast on questions.

How many of these votes you can actually use depends on the ratio of question to answer votes.

Comment: [Nice avatar Chris](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126828/combined-stack-exchange-flair-makes-me-look-creepy#comment344081_126828) :)

Comment: I think there is a special restriction that you need to vote on questions early enough to get to the full 40.

Comment: Votes on questions must be casted before the 30 votes on answers; if the user votes on 4 questions and 30 answers, the number of votes is 34.