# I created my Stack Overflow account using Google OpenID, and the profile picture is from a non-publicly accessible source

Tags: support, profile-picture, google-openid

I created an account using Google OpenID. Stack Exchange took a picture from a private album I had on Picasa. I find this interesting and disturbing. It's not a very good picture of me, hah. I have a Google+ account with two public profile pictures already.

Has anyone else had this issue when creating an account using Google as an OpenID provider?

Comment: Nice picture! .. so, i'm a lil confusd what happened again? Why it's not valid?

Comment: Did you enter an email address, in your Stack Exchange profile?

Comment: Have you used this picture for Google Talk or Gmail chat? Google can make a picture available to OAuth consumers, but I'm not sure where it's taken from. (edit: See [Selecting your Gmail picture
 - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35529) to control this, possibly.)

Comment: sorry for the delay in answering! i've never used this picture for anything, ever before. it happened to be on my picasa web account which google+ had access to, the folder the picture was is was private; i've never used it for any profile picture in google products, ever.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We do not pull a picture based on information sent directly from Google OpenId (or any other OpenId other than Facebook).

We use the [Gravatar](http://gravatar.com) service for our user images.  If you edit your profile, you will see a "change picture" link underneath the picture.  This link takes you to Gravatar's site.

If we are pulling that image for you, it means that the email you have entered in your user profile here is an email that is connected to your Gravatar account, and furthermore that the picture we are using is connected to that email address within Gravatar.

If you would like to use a different image, you will need to change the image associated with the email on Gravatar's side.  If you want to use a different image here only, but not anywhere else that uses Gravatar, you could use +-addressing.  You could add youremail+stackoverflow@gmail.com to Gravatar and then add a special image there.  This will leave anything pulling Gravatar for youremail@gmail.com unaffected.

Comment: +1 I was seriously considering posting this as an answer, but wasn't sure if the picture issue has changed, as it has with the Facebook logins.

Comment: Nope, Facebook is an exception.

Comment: Some [exception indeed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126828/combined-stack-exchange-flair-makes-me-look-creepy) ;-)

Comment: @Arjan hehe yes, that amused me. (:

Comment: @Reb - I'm glad my problems amuse you ;)

Comment: @Lix I actually meant it as a compliment.  They way you presented the bug with the meme face and Jeff/Joel was a well-done bug report. (:

Comment: @reb - My comment was sarcastic :P  I am flattered that you enjoyed my report - I enjoyed making it :P In the very serious and professional world of technology its important to break the monotony now and then.

Comment: sorry for the delay in answering! I've never set up a Gravatar account prior to setting up a stackoverflow account, if my memory serves me best. i also don't think i would ever choose that photo. thanks for your input

Comment: so I looked into it and apparently I do have a gravatar account which is linked to wordpress.com, I used to have a wordpress account years and years ago-- perhaps this is where it all started from? thanks for your help!