# What happened to the Review layout?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, review

I just browsed to the [review screen](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) and it appears that the layout is broken or at least looks broken.  There is a user's gravatar that incredibly large and it is causing a large section of white-space.

> [image]

While I love seeing the picture of a happy user, I don't think this should picture should be breaking the layout and producing the extra whitespace.  I was able to replicate this in Chrome and Firefox.

Is it due to the fact they are using a facebook image while the others listed are using gravatars?  Can this be corrected?

Comment: *It is due to the fact they are using a facebook image while the others listed are using gravatars* -> this

Comment: not a duplicate - but the answer given is related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126828/combined-stack-exchange-flair-makes-me-look-creepy

Comment: Nice way to stand out among the rest.

Comment: **I AM FACEBOOK!  HEAR ME ROAR!**

Comment: Cillian Murphy is asking questions on Stack Overflow? Cool.

Comment: @Pekka wow, I didn't even see the similarities until you said that.  Totally looks like him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Facebook profile images will no longer ROAR after the next build.

Comment: Thank you, even though I will miss the ROAR!!